# Bigquery Intraday table overwrite process

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

I want to use the intraday tables, as per docs they are overwritten approx. 3 times a day.

I want to ask that they are overwritten with new data only or till time data.

Example: Intraday table for today is created at 8 AM UTC.
Considering id is unique.

It has data for id: 1, 2, 3

When it is overwritten let's say at 16 UTC and new uds 4 and 5 came by then.

Would it have data: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  or just 3, 4, 5?

[Bigquery docs for columns](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en)

Would the fullVisitorId, hitnumber and time combination be unique across all rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, fullVisitorId, hitnumber and time combination will be unique across all rows.

**What are intraday (or realtime) tables?**

Intraday tables represent Google Analytics data for the current day. They are appended to three times a day with data lagging about two hours and are replaced with a new table when the daily sessions table is ingested to BigQuery. Alternatively, realtime tables are appended to approximately every 15 minutes. Both tables allow reporting on the current day’s analytics data.

**How can we use intraday tables?**

Because intraday tables are only overwritten in the event of a new daily table ingestion to BigQuery, **they will continue to append while also storing the data for yesterday’s sessions**. We can solve for yesterday’s missing data by incorporating logic into our data processing and reporting workflow. The logic will execute data processing queries to pull from intraday tables in the event that the daily table is not yet available.

Comment: Hello there, does this still apply?  My data has been lagging for 2 days already.